# I have three seperate inner join statements each creating a table. Can i combine all three to make a master table?

Tags: sql, solidworks

How do I get the following to appear in the same table? Is there some sort of join to string them all together? or can I declare each table as a variable then string together?

```
--Description
SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText, VariableValue.VariableID
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID
where RIGHT(filename,6) = 'SLDDRW' and VariableID = '56';

--Status
SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText, VariableValue.VariableID
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID
where RIGHT(filename,6) = 'SLDDRW' and VariableID = '46';

--Revision
SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText, VariableValue.VariableID
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID
where RIGHT(filename,6) = 'SLDDRW' and VariableID = '45';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this simplification:

```
SELECT d.Filename, vv.ValueText, vv.VariableID
FROM Documents d INNER JOIN
     VariableValue vv
     ON d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID
WHERE filename LIKE '%SLDDRW' and VariableID IN ('56', '46', '45');
```

Note:  if `VariableID` is numeric, then you should remove the single quotes from the list of values.

Comment: Thanks Gordon that is far less complicated and allows the table to be temporary. Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use INSERT INTO and UNION ALL Combination

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (Filename  VARCHAR(50),ValueText VARCHAR(50), VariableID INT);


INSERT INTO tableName
SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText, 
VariableValue.VariableID
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID
where RIGHT(filename,6) = 'SLDDRW' and VariableID = '56'

UNION ALL

SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText, 
VariableValue.VariableID
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID
where RIGHT(filename,6) = 'SLDDRW' and VariableID = '46'

UNION ALL

SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText, 
VariableValue.VariableID
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID
where RIGHT(filename,6) = 'SLDDRW' and VariableID = '45'
```

Comment: This looks great! how do I create the table to insert into? is there anyway this could be a temporary table? thanks

Comment: again this is a step towards the right direction. However, this creates a table with two columns. What I would like is for the value text and variable id to appear in separate columns. This would result in 7 columns: FileName, ValueText, VariableID, ValueText, VariableID, ValueText, VariableID. As you can see there are duplicates in the column names. As a result, I get the following 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'  Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I feel we are getting nearer! I know get the following error. of which I do not understand 'Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 4
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: @Dan Increase the column size based on your text length

Comment: In terms of combining the tables, that works great thanks! is there any way I can get variable ID 56, 46 & 45 and their associate variable value in separate columns? this currently collates them all in the same column in ascending order.

Comment: Yes I did, it only shows three columns: FileName, Value Text and Variable ID

Comment: ok that's fine, I will transpose the table in excel. Thanks for the help. I will mark question as correct.